# Best way to do unknown number of nested v-for loops, or how to do while loops in VueJs (is there a "v-while"?)

Tags: beginner, vue.js

I want to recursively use a Vue component for each item in a multidimensional array, which is a list of topics. For example, Topic 1 can have subtopics 1.1, 1.1.1 and 1.1.2, but topic 2 might have no subtopics at all. (My working code is presented at the bottom)

My Array in Vue's app `data` is something like:

```
[
  ['Topic 1', [
    'Topic 1.1', [
       ['Topic 1.1.1', []],
       ['Topic 1.1.2', []]
    ]
  ],
  ['Topic 2', []],
  ['Topic 3', [
    ['Topic 3.1', []],
    ['Topic 3.2', []],
    ['Topic 3.3', []],
    ]
  ]
]
```

Supposing my component is just a `details` tag, this is my expected HTML output (borders were added just for clarity):

```css
details > details {
  margin-left: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main id="root">
<details open><summary>Topic 1</summary>
  <details open><summary>Topic 1.1</summary>
    <details open><summary>Topic 1.1.1</summary>
    </details>
    <details open><summary>Topic 1.1.2</summary>
    </details>
  </details>
</details>
<details open><summary>Topic 2</summary>
</details>
<details open><summary>Topic 3</summary>
  <details open><summary>Topic 3.1</summary>
  </details>
  <details open><summary>Topic 3.2</summary>
  </details>
  <details open><summary>Topic 3.3</summary>
  </details>
</details>
etc.
```

I can't anticipate all `v-for` loops I'll use, because I don't know the depth of each topic (i.e., I don't know how many subtopics there are, it depends on each topic and there can be dozens or none at all).

My solution was to use a `v-if` to check if there are subarrays inside the current array; if there are, a component is created for the subarrays too (and the component's template includes in the end this `div` with a `v-if`, so it works recursively).

This works, but looks clunky. *So my question is: what is the best way to run a while-loop with Vue (for the cases where I don't know how many for-loops I need to run)?* Or is my solution already the best way to approach this?

(I first thought of creating a `method`, and calling this method in the end to check if there are subarrays and then create components for them basically via JavaScript, but this seems worse than using `v-if` and adding a `v-for` for adding components to the subarray items)

---

Here's my working code:

```js
Vue.component('details-component', {
  template: `<details><summary> {{ arritem[0] }} </summary><div v-if="arritem[1].length"> <div v-for="subitem in arritem[1]">
    <details-component :arritem="subitem"></details-component> </div></details>`,
  props: {
    arritem: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    arr: [
      ['Topic 1', [
        ['Topic 1.1', [
          ['Topic 1.1.1', []],
          ['Topic 1.1.2', []]
          ]
        ]
      ]],
      ['Topic 2', []],
      ['Topic 3', [
        ['Topic 3.1', []],
        ['Topic 3.2', []],
        ['Topic 3.3', []],
      ]]
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
details details {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<main id="root">
  <div v-for="item in arr">
    <details-component :arritem="item"></details-component>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `v-while`, no. You can however use `v-for` over a computed property (which you can compute using `while` if you so wish).

Although I don't see a reason to use any while-loop. What you have is a data structure with topics and subtopics of any arbitrary length. Using a recursive component for this, which you have done here, is a good choice.

About the only thing that I would change is to, instead of using `arritem[0]` and `arritem[1]`, using an object with properties `name` and `children`. This can possibly also help you determine if a component has any children or not.

Comment: Thank you, that's great advice! And that's a good idea too in regard to the computed property, it's better than me simply using a method for cases like this, that I want to cache the result